# How many times is c found in n

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, return

```
n = int(input("Input n: "))
c = int(input("Input c: "))

def it_show(n, c):
    counter= 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i < 10:
            if i == c:
                counter+= 1
        if i > 9:
            digit = i % 10
            if digit == c:
                counter+= 1
            i //= 10
    return counter

print(it_show(n, c))
```

From the start sory my English is not so good.

**In the task it is emphasizes to work with numbers, no strings.**

I need to input n and c.Program need to return in how many numbers from 1 to n(including n), c show up.Etc. n=20 and c=5 return is 2.Because from 1 to 20, 5 show up in numbers 5 and 15, that is 2 numbers.In this code for this case it works.But if I input n=14 and c=1 return is 2, but it needs to bee 6 because from 1 to 14(including 14) there are 6 numbers that have c(1) in them (1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14).

Comment: Don't work with numbers but with strings, checking for the occurrence of the substring or character

Comment: So, can you work with **array** or **list** of numbers?

Comment: No, but list is next lesson so if you can show me how to solve this with list.Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` to cycle through the digits.

```
def it_show(n, c):

  counter = 0

  for i in range(1, n+1):

    while i > 0:

      if i % 10 == c: # if the right digit is equal to c
        counter += 1
        break # counter increased, and no need to check the other digits

      i //= 10 # integer division to eliminate the right digit, which was already checked

  return counter

print(it_show(20,5))
print(it_show(14,1))
```

Comment: Not working.For input n=14 and c=1 output is: 2 and unter it 6

Comment: The first prints "2", the second prints "6". Isn't that correct?

Comment: No, from 1 to 14(including 14) are 6 numbers that have c(1) in them. 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.So output need to be 6 only.

Comment: ?? It's printing "2" and "6" because I put those two test cases at the end of the code. If you prefer, you can just copy the function. The prints are outside the function.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see.My bad

Comment: If I understood correctly num=i, that means num equal number we are checking at the moment.
With num>0 we are creating an infinite loop that we are gonna break if num==c.
If num is not == to c we are gonna remove the last right digit and repeat the loop until it is ==.
Am I right?

Comment: Regarding num = i, it is just a personal preference. You don't need num - you can use i for the calculations. Honestly, I didn't even think about it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Regarding the logic, the idea, if I understood the question, is to check each digit of a given ```i```. The ```break``` statement comes from the fact that, we may not need to check all digits. For instance, if i is 12 and we are looking for "2", then once we see the right digit matches, we don't need to check the left digit. On the other hand, if the right digit doesn't match, then we have to check the left digit, which may or may not match.

Comment: By doing ```i % 10``` we get the remainder of the integer division by 10, which corresponds (in the specific case of 10) to the right most digit. As you say, if the right digit does not match we remove it. How? By an integer division ```i // 10```. Notice the double "//". This removal, works for the specific case of the division by 10. Say we are now analysing "8", at the end of the inner code, 8 // 10 = 0. So the next time the ```while``` condition gets tested, it will be false, and the ```while``` will be terminated.

Comment: It is sometimes useful to take a pen and a paper, and, for some examples, write down all the steps and all the values that the variables take on each step.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input("Input n: "))
c = int(input("Input c: "))

def it_show(n, c):
    sc = str(c)
    counter= 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if str(i).count(sc):
            counter += 1
    return counter

print(it_show(n, c))
```

compare strings like this will make it simpler to understand and (likely) faster.

Comment: In the task it is emphasizes to work with numbers

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you convert numbers to string and then count the number of `numbers` from digits:

```py
n = int(input("Input n: "))
c = int(input("Input c: "))

def it_show(n, c):
    counter= 0
    c_str = str(c)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        num_str = str(i)
        if c_str in num_str:    # if number c exists in number i
            counter += 1
    return counter

print(it_show(n, c))
```

**Output**

```py
Input n: 14
Input c: 1
6
```

Comment: No it need to be 6 because return is not how many times c(1) i showed up but in how many numbers is showed up.

Comment: Thank  you this is so much easier but in my task it is emphasizes to work with numbers.But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a number is a substring of another number as a string.

```
n = 14
c = 1

def it_show(n, c):
    counter=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if str(c) in str(i):
            counter+= 1
    return counter

print(it_show(n, c))
```

[**Output**]

```
6
```

Comment: In the task it is emphasizes to work with numbers